# What differences are there between the editions of Grossman's translation of Don Quixote?

Tags: translation, textual-history, spanish-language, don-quixote, miguel-de-cervantes

Putting aside the physical (like the cover, flaps etc.), what, if any, differences are there between these three editions of Edith Grossman's translation of Don Quixote? Are the annotations the same in all? Supplementary material? Harold Bloom's introduction? Or are they, in terms of content, completely the same?

- Vintage Books (2005), ISBN: 0099469693
- Ecco (2015), ISBN: 0062391666
- Ecco (2005), ISBN: 0060934344

Comment: A quick search on all 3 ISBNs indicates that the Vintage ed. doesn't mention the introduction, while the 2015 is a deluxe edition of the 2005 Ecco. I would vote to close if I had enough privileges on this forum.

Comment: @KateBunting A quick search falls short of certainty, I'm afraid. I was able to get my hands on the Vintage ed. and it does, in fact, feature Bloom's introduction, despite making no mention of it in the cover. My impression so far is that the Ecco (2005) and Vintage editions are contentwise identical. The Vintage ed. is complete with: Translator's Note to the Reader, Bloom's introduction, the text itself and full annotations. Can't say what the Ecco (2015) ed. adds or changes, if anything.